# SendInput or similar from windows service (session 0) in Windows 8 to login screen

Tags: windows, winapi, service, windows-8, rdp

As I understand, when we start windows it starts Session 0 which does not connect to any GUI, etc. and runs all windows services. So my task is, after windows was started, emulate windows input for selecting user and login to is session. I know that for sending input from service I should run desktop app and through it send input, show GUI, so on, but how can I do it before any user session was start? (for example I see that TeamViewer can do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835(v=vs.85).aspx) will tell you which session is attached to the physical console.

You can then duplicate your security token with [DuplicateTokenEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617(v=vs.85).aspx), change the new token's session with [SetTokenInformation()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379591(v=vs.85).aspx) and the `TokenSessionId` option, and launch a process with [CreateProcessAsUser()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx).

The new process should then be running in the right session, but it may also need to attach itself to the right desktop before it can interact with the logon interface.  You can use [EnumDesktops()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682614(v=vs.85).aspx) to list the available desktops, and trial and error to determine which one the logon interface runs in.  (Note that this may be different in different versions of Windows.)